# Expenditure function only dependent on prices

Tags: microeconomics, utility, demand

I'm struggling with a problem where I want to derive the Hicksian demand from a given expenditure function $e(p,u)$. I would do that by using Shephard's Lemma, so that the first partial derivative of $e$ with respect to $p_i$ gives the Hicksian demand for good $i$. My problem is, however, that the expenditure function given does only depend on prices, not on $u$ (which does not make any sense to me since $e$ should minimize the costs given a certain utility level, so it is clearly dependent on $u$). The function is given as $e(p,u) = p_1^{1/4}*(-p_2^{1/3})$. Checking on the homogeneity of $e$ in prices, also does not lead me to a homogeneity of degree $1$ which contradicts the properties of the expenditure function. Am I overlooking something important? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: There is obviously a problem in your expenditure function. This is not an expenditure function for a rational consumer, and not sur that her demand function can be obtained by Shephard's lemma in this context.

Comment: Is there possibly something else in the problem that could allow you to convert the form of the expenditure function to something containing utility?

Comment: Thank you! I only know that for e: D -> R, where D = {(p, u)|p,u >}